# Convert a string to date in logstash in json DATA

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

From this source data

```
2022-01-21 12:25:01,339 {"category":"runtime","some_id":"order","correlation_id":"OEID_1","servid":"143","provision_id":"898769049","operation_name":"CREATE", "processing_state":"ACTIVE","lifecycle_state":"ACTIVE","created":"2022-01-21 12:25:00,369","changed":"2022-01-21 12:25:00,806","runtime":"0.437"}
```

and my basic logstash config

```
filter {

  grok {
    match => { message => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}%{SPACE}*%{DATA:json}$" }
    add_tag => [ "matched", "provisioning_runtime" ]
  }

  json {
    source => "json"
    add_tag => [ "json" ]
  }

  # matcher for the @timestamp
  date {
    match => [ "logdate", "ISO8601", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
  }
```

i tried to convert the created field from string to a date field, but not replacing the @timestamp field. How to insert this in the config, i dont understand this, all i tried doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
 date {
    match => [ "logdate", "ISO8601", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    target => "logdate"
  }
```

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target)'s the documentation.

Comment: Yes i know this, but i was not able to use that with more than one date field. Only one timestamp to use is documented, not for more. Every time i ran into in undecriptive syntax errors.

Comment: yes, you can only have a timefield per index pattern, but you can have more than one date field. The date filter by default targets the @timestamp.

Comment: Thank you. I missed the information that i can do the date module multiple times instead trying it all in date modul

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to convert created and changed to date values as well. This can be done like this:

```
filter {

  grok {
    match => { message => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}%{SPACE}*%{DATA:json}$" }
    add_tag => [ "matched", "provisioning_runtime" ]
  }

  json {
    source => "json"
    add_tag => [ "json" ]
  }

  # matcher for the @timestamp
  date {
    match => [ "logdate", "ISO8601", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
  }

  # matcher for the created
  date {
    match => [ "created", "ISO8601", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    target => "created"
  }

  # matcher for the changed
  date {
    match => [ "changed", "ISO8601", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    target => "changed"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed the information that i can do the date module multiple times instead trying it all in date modul.